# Rank of a torsion-free sheaf and its restriction

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $F$ be a torsion-free sheaf of rank $r$ on a smooth projective variety $X$ over complex numbers. Let $D$ be a irreducible smooth divisor such that $F|_D$ is also torsion-free. This happens for a general divisor in a globally generated linear system, for example.

In this case, is it true that $rank (F)=rank(F|_D)$?

I think this is true. This is my argument. If $F$ is torsion-free, there is an open set $U$ such that $F|_U$ is locally free. The complement of this set has codimension at least 2 in $X$. Hence $D$ is not contained in this complement. $D\cap U$ is a dense open subet of $U$. Hence $rank F|_D= rank F|_{U\cap D}$. This gives us the required result. Is this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only true, if $F$ is coherent. If not, we have the following counter example:

Let $X$ be integral and let $F=K(X)$ be the constant sheaf with values in the function field of $X$ (i.e. the sheaf of meromorphic functions). Then $F$ has rank $1$, but $F_{|D}=0$.

Algebraically this is just $\operatorname{Frac}(R) \otimes_R R/I = 0$ for any integral domain $R$ and $I \neq 0$.

Your proof fails at the very first step, where you claim local freeness: Any module is free at the generic point, but to get an open set where it is free, one needs it to be finitely generated.

---

Edit: If you dont consider $0$ as torsion-free (because its support is empty), just take $F = K(X) \oplus \mathcal O_X$. Then $F_{|D} = \mathcal O_D$ is torsion-free and the rank lowered from two to one.

Comment: Thanks! Thankfully I am dealing with only coherent sheaves. So in that case there is no problem right.

Comment: Yes, in that case there is no problem. I think it goes without saying for you, but one could explain it a little bit more I think: when you claim that  the non-locally free locus has at least co-dimension $2$, you use that a noetherian one-dimensional regular local ring is a PID and in a PID torsion-free = free for **finitely generated** modules.

Comment: absolutely. Thank you!